# Render BibLaTeX Key and generate plain text bibliography

Tags: markdown, pandoc, citations, biblatex

I would like to render the BibLaTeX keys in my markdown file and add a bibliography at the end of the text. Currently I use in a powershell script
`pandoc -s $Markdown --bibliography "C:\...\ref.bib" --csl "C:\...\styles\apa.csl" --citeproc --metadata link-citations=flase --to=gfm --output "$MarkDown-out.md"`

Unfortunately HTML markup is added, which certain platforms other than Github do not render.
How to generate a plain-text list of references or bibliographies in simple markdown?

```
<div id="refs" class="references csl-bib-body hanging-indent" line-spacing="2">
<div id="ref-MySource" class="csl-entry">
My Source
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: After some more trial and error setting the format to `--to=markdown_strict` produces only Markdown output without any HTML. However, certain CSL arguments such as [`second-field-align`](https://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/specification.html?highlight=second-field-align#whitespace) have to be avoided. Now, I am stuck trying to prevent pandoc from escaping the period character when added after the citation-number with the suffix attribute in the CSL.